# Angular material calendar selected date alignment issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have updated Angular material version from 12 to 15. but after upgrading it, I am getting following issue in date pickers calendar.

but that alignment issue is goes if we click anywhere, or even when switching windows.

It looks like digest cycle issue. so I tried using **ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges** while opening calendar but it didn't work.

[[image: Issue with selected date alignment.]]

Html:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
  <mat-label>{{ lable }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [value]="defaultValue" [min]="minDate"
    [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="open()"
    (focus)="open()" (dateChange)="emitDate($event.value)"/>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker [touchUi]="isMobile$ | async" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
  open() {
    this.picker.open();
    this.cRef.detectChanges()
  }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's really not possible to help with this without seeing the code.

Comment: @NigelPeck added code for question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have resolved this issue.

Issue was caused due to some pseudo class getting attached to calendar cell at the time of selection. when I used to click anywhere in the screen or try to do any interaction on screen this class used to get removed from selected element and position was getting corrected.

Original class:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell:focus .mat-focus-indicator::before{
  content: "";
}
```

Overwriten class which resolved the issue:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell:focus .mat-focus-indicator::before{
  content: normal !important;
}
```